# Bash erro when finishing with EOF

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I apologize in advance if the message do not seem appropriate here but i believe it is the good place.

I got this strange error when i execute my bash script:

```
./cluster_bootstrap.sh 
./cluster_bootstrap.sh: line 15: $'\r': command not found
./cluster_bootstrap.sh: line 91: warning: here-document at line 37 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./cluster_bootstrap.sh: line 92: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Meanwhile everything seems correct when i copy paste the script in my shell.
Any idea of this odd behaviour ?

PS: Here is my script:

```
address=192.168.1.101
# DNS (Celui du FAI est: 80.10.246.130 ; tandis que celui de google est 8.8.8.8)
nameserver=8.8.8.8
#Hostname
hostname=slave1
#Hosts
hostname_master=master
address_master=192.168.1.100
hostname_slave1=slave1
address_slave1=192.168.1.101
hostname_slave2=slave2
address_slave2=192.168.1.102
#__I) ________ Configuration d'une ip statique pour le bridge Network__________ 
#0) Install ifupdown et resolvconf
if [ -z  `which resolvconf` ]
then
    echo "sudo apt install resolvconf is required"
    sudo apt install resolvconf
else
    echo "resolvconf is already installed!"
fi

if [ -z  `which ifup` ]
then
    echo "sudo apt install ifupdown  is required"
    sudo apt install resolvconf
else
    echo "ifupdown is already installed!"
    echo "Super!"
fi


#1) Configurer l'adresse statique 
#cat  << EOF | sudo tee  /etc/network/interfaces
sudo tee  /etc/network/interfaces << EOF
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
address $address
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
EOF

sudo ifup enp0s3

#2) Configurer le DNS

sudo tee   /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail  << EOF 
nameserver $nameserver
EOF

#3)
#sudo reboot

#__II) ________ Configuration de clés ssh_________

#1) hostname
echo "hostname=$hostname"
echo "$hostname " | sudo tee  /etc/hostname

#2) hosts
sudo tee   /etc/hosts  << EOF 
127.0.0.1 localhost
$address_master $hostname_master
$address_slave1 $hostname_slave1
$address_slave2 $hostname_slave2

EOF
```

Comment: Have you transfer this script from Windows machine? Have you try to use `dos2unix`?

Comment: Perhaps i did some copy paste beween my windows host and my linux guest. I don't know dos2unix but i can check. anyway isn't it odd that a copy paste in terminal doesn't return the same result that executing bash my_script ? Thanks

Comment: @PincemailleLaurent Copying and pasting a printed file will remove nonprinting characters like carriage return, which is probably what's causing the problem. See [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: Thank you to both of you! dos2unix worked perfectly! Cheers.